# How do you render a list of square Views in a FlatList in react native?

Tags: css, react-native

Say that you want to render two columns of squares in a `FlatList` so it looks like a scrollable square grid and is responsive to different screen sizes.

What CSS properties in react-native are required to make each `<Item/>` in the FlatList square?

I've tried `aspectRatio` and it does not work.

Using the CSS property `paddingTop : '50%'` works for those which have a complete row but as you can see it doesn't work for the bottom.

[image]

```
import React from 'react'
import {View, FlatList, StyleSheet, Dimensions} from 'react-native'

const screen_length = Math.max(Dimensions.get('window').height, Dimensions.get('window').width)

const screen_width = Math.min(Dimensions.get('window').height, Dimensions.get('window').width)
   
const length_factor = screen_length/844
const width_factor = screen_width/390

const StyleSheet.create.({
  container:{
    display: 'flex',
    flex:1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    justifyItems: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    alignContent: 'center',
    width: '100%',
    height:'100%',
    flexDirection: '100%'
  },
  square:{
    flex:1 ,
    aspectRatio: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    borderColor: 'yellow',
    borderWidth: 5,
    borderRadius: 10,
    width:Math.round( width_factor * 150),
    paddingTop:'50%',
  }
 })

 const DATA = [ {id: 1}, {id:2} , {id: 3} ]

 const Item = ({item}) => {
   <View style = {styles.square} />
 }


export default function Test() {
  renderItem = ({item})=> {
    return(
      <Item />
    )
  }

  return(
    <FlatList
      data = {DATA}  
      renderItem = {renderItem}
      keyExtractor = {item => item.theme}
      numColumns = {2}
      style ={{flex:1, width:'100%', height: '100%'}}
      contentContainerStyle = {styles.container}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: what is the last square in the screenshot?

Comment: @novonimo well that is the last item. If i have only one item in the last row then it doesn't display properly (i.e the last item is a rectangle rather than a square)

Comment: Just fyi writing rendering logic using arbitrary constants and having to perform manual calculations of things involving widths and heights is usually an indication the overall approach is wrong. If one day you decide to add some spacing between the squares, all the calculations have to change and become even more complex. There must be a better way to do this using flex, but admittidly I do not know what it is right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, FlatList, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const screen_length = Math.max(
  Dimensions.get('window').height,
  Dimensions.get('window').width
);

const screen_width = Math.min(
  Dimensions.get('window').height,
  Dimensions.get('window').width
);

const length_factor = screen_length / 844;
const width_factor = screen_width / 390;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  square: {
    flexGrow: 0,
    flexShrink: 1,
    flexBasis: '50%',
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    borderColor: 'yellow',
    borderWidth: 5,
    borderRadius: 10,
    paddingTop: '50%',
  },
  row: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
  },
});

const DATA = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }];

const Item = ({ item }) => <View style={styles.square} />;
const renderItem = ({ item }) => <Item />;

const App = () => {
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={DATA}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      numColumns={2}
      columnWrapperStyle={styles.row}
    />
  );
};

export default App;
```

https://snack.expo.dev/@ksav/greedy-ice-cream